# Why is the first one not an inner product but the second one is?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

$\langle p,q \rangle = \int_{-1}^1 p^\ast(t)q(t)tdt$ over $\mathbb{P}$

$\langle p,q \rangle = \int_{-1}^1 p^\ast(t)q(t)(t+1)dt$ over $\mathbb{P}$

I believe positivity works for both of them, and I am unsure of how to show the other ways of proving an inner product.

The star denotes complex conjugate.

Comment: What's $\mathbb P$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, please refer to this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: HINT: set $p=q=1$ in the first definition.

Answer (score 1):

Positivity condition fails.

Take p,q as 1.

$<p,p>=0$ for first case as

$\int_{-1}^1 t= \frac{t^2}{2}|_{-1}^1$

$t^2=1-1=0$